# hide windows taskbar on page load

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to hide windows taskbar during page load of an aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There used to be such option in IE, but as it was abused by malware (e.g. it hid the real taskbar and pretended there was a virus on the computer, then scared the user into downloading the real virus), it was removed.

In general, the code inside the browser has no business messing with anything outside the browser, for security reasons.

If you have control over the clients' computers (e.g. for an internal application that will be used from specific computers) and you know which browser(s) will be used, you could write a browser plugin (or an extension, in case of Firefox/Chrome/Opera) and install it on those computers - these have a much higher privileges of access to the rest of the OS, almost like normal processes.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible without using some proprietary plugin inside the browser.